# xPages Extension Library v9 and JDBC installation issue

Tags: jdbc, xpages

I just installed Notes Client 9.0.1FP5 SHF190 and Extension Library is a part of the product. But it doesn't contain com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library. Well, I took it in latest "ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v00_16.20160128-1014.zip" release and installed it through File->Application->Install with no errors. But JDBS is still not available as a data source:

```
<xe:jdbcRowSet... or <xe:jdbcQuery...
```

In xPage properties I still says the library is not installed. Please, advise.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDBMS support is no longer part of extlibx, since release 7 of the 901 extlib. You need to install the full extlib v16 designer update site to domino designer. From your screenshot it looks like you've only got the default 901 extlib (effectively v0). And also install the extlib 16 update site to your server.

You could check out this video made around the time of the work to move the RDBMS support from extlibx into the main extlib.

http://youtu.be/zoiOVCfeEB0

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the extension library in BOTH designer AND the server.  I'm guessing that it's not on the server.